# Extract up to three strings of varying length with regex pattern on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

**GOAL**

In a Microsoft SQL Server table I have a string column. The column contains up to three so-called ICD-codes which specify a disease. 
The goal is to extract up to three strings of varying length from each row and store them in 3 columns. If less than three codes are found, NAs can be used. For example if there is only one valid code the first column should be filled with the code, and the remaining two should contain NAs.

**BACKGROUND**

ICD-codes are of varying length and are so structured

```
[Letter][2 to 4 numbers][optional letter]
```

Each row can contain up to 3 ICD-codes. The codes are not separated by anything and are written after each other. Often there is also junk in the middle.

I wrote (with a little help from my friends at stackoverflow) a regex that successfully extracts these three codes when used in R with the function str_match_all. The regex is

```
(?i)(?=([A-Z]\\d{2,4}(?:[A-Z](?!\\d{2,4}))?))
```

Problem is, I cannot figure out how to do this in SQL Server.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How to extract several substrings of varying length from a string in Microsoft SQL Server?
2. (optional) How to "pipe" the extracted string into three columns?

**EXAMPLE**

A minimal example of the data I have can be found here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a65f1

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (diagnosis varchar(100), diagnosis_1 varchar(10), diagnosis_2 varchar(10), diagnosis_3 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO table1 (diagnosis)
VALUES
("T038MFRACTURE"),
("M719BOCHCM531"),
("F900CF334M75");
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
diagnosis, diagnosis_1,diagnosis_2,diagnosis_3
T038MFRACTURE,T038M,NULL,NULL
M719BOCHCM531,M719B,M531,NULL
F900CF334M75,F900C,F334,M75
```

Comment: From where `549` come from in `T038M549`? What is the logic?

Comment: A mistake. Corrected the expected result. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Hi, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: Sorry, I have not had time to review this question. I would like to wrap my head around your solution before accepting it :) Hope you can wait a little longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (diagnosis varchar(100), diagnosis_1 varchar(10), diagnosis_2 varchar(10), diagnosis_3 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO table1 (diagnosis)
VALUES
('T038MFRACTURE'),
('M719BOCHCM531'),
('F900CF334M75');
```

--The query uses a recursive CTE first to find the positions of a character followed by a number (the start of an ICD code)

```
WITH PosOfNonNumer AS
(
    SELECT diagnosis AS Original
          ,diagnosis
          ,1 AS PartIndex
          ,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%',diagnosis) AS PosFound
          ,SUBSTRING(diagnosis,1,5) AS PartFound
          ,SUBSTRING(diagnosis,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%',diagnosis)+2,1000) AS RestString
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.Original
          ,p.RestString
          ,p.PartIndex+1
          ,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%',p.RestString) AS PosFound
          ,SUBSTRING(p.RestString,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%',p.RestString),5) AS PartFound
          ,SUBSTRING(p.RestString,PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%', p.RestString)+2,1000) AS RestString
    FROM PosOfNonNumer AS p
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%',p.RestString)>0
)
```

--The main query uses conditional aggregation to pivot your results

```
SELECT Original
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PartIndex=1 THEN PartFound END) AS diag1 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PartIndex=2 THEN PartFound END) AS diag2 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PartIndex=3 THEN PartFound END) AS diag3 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN PartIndex=4 THEN PartFound END) AS diag4 
FROM PosOfNonNumer
GROUP BY Original
GO

--clean-up
--DROP TABLE table1;
```

The result

```
Original        diag1   diag2   diag3   diag4
F900CF334M75    F900C   F334M   M75     NULL
M719BOCHCM531   M719B   M531    NULL    NULL
T038MFRACTURE   T038M   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

You will have to cut away some characters at the end... Hope you can manage this yourself...

Comment: In what case would I need to cut characters at the end?

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist, I don't know... You write *[Letter][2 to 4 numbers][optional letter]*. Could it be, that the optional letter is missing, but there is additional content (e.g. `T038FRACTURE` instead of `T038MFRACTURE`)? In this case the "F" of "FRACTURE" would pop up as *optional letter*

Comment: Yes, that is a good example. I will go ahead and accept your answer anyway, as it does behave as expected from my question. Thanks!